# Duplicate classes R & BuildConfig after "Reimport All Maven Projects"

Tags: android, maven, intellij-idea

We are building our Android projects with Maven and IntelliJ IDEA. Sometimes we must execute "Reimport All Maven Projects", e.g. to update dependencies. The problem with that is that it always messes up the source folders for resources: all modules get "gen" and "target/generated-source/r" which seems to be the cause for the duplicates. So after reimporting, we need to manually delete one of those (usually the "gen" folder). Of course, we want to avoid this step. We tried several settings for the Android facet, but no luck so far.

So, how can we configure IntelliJ to do a proper Maven reimport that just works?

Comment: Maybe your project structure differ from the maven default which is target/generated-source etc. Have a look at this: http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-one-source-directory.html

Comment: @greenrobot is there any solution with this? I'm having this problem on maven and really stucked over here :( the weird thing is it was working until yesterday evening, suddenly it started to keep saying duplicate class R and BuildConfig.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the reply of Sven Strohschein at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-94901 you can try to:

1. Delete the "gen", "target" and "out" folders
2. Revert the changes within the "ipr" and "iml" files (or just delete them all, maybe even .idea folder)
3. Start IntelliJ 12
4. Open the pom file
5. Right click -> "Maven" -> "Reimport"
6. "Build" -> "Rebuild project"

Works fo me.

Answer (score 1):

After IDEA detects and adds Android facet to module, it would start generating `gen` folder at usual place, but `maven-android-plugin` generates its own under `target` directory.

You need to tell IDEA to place generated files at same place where `maven-android-plugin` creates them.

First, use module's android facet settings and check the option to use Maven goal instead of generating by itself:

[image]

Then, go to  module's settings and set output path same as Maven's, which is `target` directory:

[image]

Delete `gen` directories, Do `mvn clean` to clear all unnecessary files.

Answer (score 0):

From your description above I guess that your project structure differs from the maven default. See [Introduction to the POM](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html). But I think the android [android:generate-sources](http://maven-android-plugin-m2site.googlecode.com/svn/generate-sources-mojo.html) is more interesting if you have changed the assets directory etc.

Example:

```
<sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src</sourceDirectory> 
<outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes</outputDirectory>
```

Comment: Yes, it differs from the standard Maven layout. The directory is the old-school Android layout with src and gen folders directly in the project root directory. Do you have concrete suggestions?

Comment: I changed my post. I don't have a android project so I cannot test the android:generate-sources configuration. I think you have to change some details of that.

Comment: Not sure about this approach: We already have <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>, and the default for the res folder is already ${project.basedir}/res.

Comment: R.java has a seperate configuration see my link above about android maven plugin.

Comment: I added <genDirectory>gen</genDirectory> to the configuration of the maven-android plugin, but still see build errors when using IntelliJ...