# Android build - "duplicate class: com.myapp.R"

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm stumped by this build error. It appears it may be related to using AppCompat, as if I remove that dependency from the build file the build error is no longer present. I am not using product flavors, and actually this project is very simple indeed - one Android module, a few classes and some resources. I'm using the Android Studio beta, 0.89 (latest).

I searched the source tree and can see two files called R.java, one in the app namespace the other in the AppCompat namespace.

Related is a second build error:
"duplicate class: com.myapp.BuildConfig.java

Searching reveals only one file with that name in the project.

What does this build error mean, and how do I fix it?

### build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.0'

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try deleting your R.java file, and then rebuilding the project.

If that doesn't work, [try doing this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18537553/1396572)

> 1. Delete the "gen", "target" and "out" folders
> 2. Revert the changes within the "ipr" and "iml" files (or just delete them all, maybe even .idea folder)
> 3. Start IntelliJ 12
> 4. Open the pom file
> 5. Right click -> "Maven" -> "Reimport"
> 6. "Build" -> "Rebuild project"

Comment: I've tried a clean build, and I've also recreated the Android Studio project from scratch, neither has resolved it. I'm struggling to see where the state is that is causing the problem.

Comment: Okay, I've edited it to include the salient details.